# merge two arrays based on array1

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to **merge** two arrays for the values of array1 that are set

```
Array1 ( [0] => false [1] => 200 )
Array2 ( [0] => true [1] => 80 [2] => 60 [3] => 75 [4] => 50 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 30 [8] => 40 )
```

for instance result array:

```
Array3 ( [0] => false [1] => 200 [2] => 60 [3] => 75 [4] => 50 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 30 [8] => 40 )
```

what would be an efficient way to handle this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the array union operator.

```
$array3 = $array1 + $array2;
```